# how to assign an arraylist value to a button

Tags: java, button, arraylist, netbeans

I am making a vending machine in which there are 6 slots within the vending machine, each with its own soda. We are to have an arraylist of enums for the brands of the sodas. I have created the buttons for each of the canslots but do not know how to assign an arraylist value for one can slot to the appropriate button as well as to have once you click the button for the canslot to decrease by 1 until it is empty.

My code for the actual vending machine is here:

```
public class VendingFrame extends JFrame {
private ArrayList<CanSlot> CanSlots = new ArrayList<>();
public VendingFrame() {
    CanSlots.add(new CanSlot(Brand.PEPSI));
    CanSlots.add(new CanSlot(Brand.COKE));
    CanSlots.add(new CanSlot(Brand.SUNKIST));
    CanSlots.add(new CanSlot(Brand.DIETPEPSI));
    CanSlots.add(new CanSlot(Brand.MTDEW));
    CanSlots.add(new CanSlot(Brand.SPRITE)); 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Pepsi");
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Coke");
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    JButton button3 = new JButton("Diest Pepsi");
    button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    JButton button4 = new JButton("Sunkist");
    button4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    JButton button5 = new JButton("Mountain Dew");
    button5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    JButton button6 = new JButton("Sprite");
    button6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    JPanel picpanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));
    add(panel);
    picpanel.add(label);
    label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\iacol\\Desktop\\cans.jpg.jpg"));
    buttonPanel.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
    buttonPanel.add(button2);
    button2.addActionListener(new ClickListener2());
    buttonPanel.add(button3);
    button3.addActionListener(new ClickListener3());
    buttonPanel.add(button4);
    button4.addActionListener(new ClickListener4());
    buttonPanel.add(button5);
    button5.addActionListener(new ClickListener5());
    buttonPanel.add(button6);
    button6.addActionListener(new ClickListener6());
    add(picpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    setSize(700, 700);
    setTitle("Vending Machine");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make, `HashMap<Button, List<Product>>();`
Using how to id the Button object and retrieve the button list on the value.

Comment: How exactly would I write this? What does this bit of code actually do. I'm a bit confused, we have never worked with this type/ bit of code before